# How to make columns right aligned in a wide table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm grateful for the advice I got from this community before on how to make columns right aligned in wide tables. But now I cannot domesticate the following table that has 15 columns and some of which contain negative numbers. In addition, I lost the track on how to make the columns right aligned. Suggestions are welcome! Thank you.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters

% Paquetes necesarios para las tablas 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,calc}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page size parameters suitably
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}}
%%%

\begin{document}



\begin{table}[th]
\footnotesize
\sf
\caption{\sf Adultos mayores beneficiarios previsionales según grupo de edades y conformación del hogar, en \%}
\label{tab:table32}


\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{15}{Z} @{}}
\toprule \toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{65 a 69 años}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{70 a 74 años}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{75 a 79 años}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{80 y más años}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Total} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-13}
\cmidrule(lr){14-16}
& 2003 & 2013 & Var.
& 2003 & 2013 & Var.
& 2003 & 2013 & Var.
& 2003 & 2013 & Var.
& 2003 & 2013 & Var.\\
\midrule
Hogar unipersonal
& 20,8 & 16,3 & $-$4,5
& 19,3 & 23,5 & 4,2
& 30,2 & 29,0 & $-$1,2
& 35,6 & 31,0 & $-$4.6
& 26,8 & 24,7 & $-$2,1 \\
Hogar bipersonal - un solo beneficiario
& 6,3 & 1,8 & $-$4,5
& 17,0 & 1,3 & $-$15,7
& 13,1 & 0,2 & $-$12,9
& 10,0 & 0,7 & $-$9,3
& 11,9 & 1,0 & $-$10,9 \\
Hogar bipersonal - dos beneficiarios
& 10,5 & 23,9 & 13,4
& 20,2 & 26,4 & 6,2
& 15,7 & 29,6 & 13,9
& 13,4 & 26,0 & 12,6
& 15,3 & 26,4 & 11,1 \\
Hogar multipersonal
& 62,4 & 58,0 & $-$4,4
& 43,4 & 48,8 & 5,4
& 41,0 & 41,2 & 0,1
& 40,9 & 42,3 & 1,4
& 46,0 & 48,0 & 1,9 \\
\\
\multicolumn{16}{l}{Adultos mayores en hogares unipersonales\textsuperscript{a}} \\
    Varones  & 28,3 & 28,9 & 0,6
    & 21,1 & 27,8 & 6,7
    & 23,1 & 24,1 & 1,0
    & 22,3 & 23,8 & 1,5
    & 23,3 & 25,7 & 2,5 \\
    Mujeres  & 71,7 & 71,1 & $-$0,6
    & 78,9 & 72,2 & $-$6,7
    & 76,9 & 75,9 & $-$1,0
    & 77,7 & 76,2 & $-$1,5
    & 76,7 & 74,3 & $-$2,5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tablenotes}
      \footnotesize
      \smallskip
      \item a: Como porcentaje del total de hogares unipersonales conformados por adultos mayores.
      \item Fuente: Elaboración propia en base a la EPH.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tabular data is mostly numeric, so I would like to suggest that you use `siunitx` to align the numbers at the decimal marker.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[detect-all,output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[th]
  \footnotesize
  \caption{Adultos mayores beneficiarios previsionales según grupo de edades y conformación del hogar, en \%}
  \label{tab:table32}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
      @{}
      l
      @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
      *{5}{
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=-2.1]
      }
      @{}
      }
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{65 a 69 años}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{70 a 74 años}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{75 a 79 años}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{80 y más años}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Total} \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
      \cmidrule(lr){8-10} \cmidrule(lr){11-13}
      \cmidrule(lr){14-16}
      & {2003} & {2013} & {Var.}
      & {2003} & {2013} & {Var.}
      & {2003} & {2013} & {Var.}
      & {2003} & {2013} & {Var.}
      & {2003} & {2013} & {Var.}\\
      \midrule
      Hogar unipersonal
      & 20.8 & 16.3 & -4.5
      & 19.3 & 23.5 &  4.2
      & 30.2 & 29.0 & -1.2
      & 35.6 & 31.0 & -4.6
      & 26.8 & 24.7 & -2.1 \\
      Hogar bipersonal \\
      -- un solo beneficiario
      &  6.3 & 1.8 & -4.5
      & 17.0 & 1.3 & -15.7
      & 13.1 & 0.2 & -12.9
      & 10.0 & 0.7 & -9.3
      & 11.9 & 1.0 & -10.9 \\
      -- dos beneficiarios
      & 10.5 & 23.9 & 13.4
      & 20.2 & 26.4 & 6.2
      & 15.7 & 29.6 & 13.9
      & 13.4 & 26.0 & 12.6
      & 15.3 & 26.4 & 11.1 \\
      Hogar multipersonal
      & 62.4 & 58.0 & -4.4
      & 43.4 & 48.8 & 5.4
      & 41.0 & 41.2 & 0.1
      & 40.9 & 42.3 & 1.4
      & 46.0 & 48.0 & 1.9 \\
      \\
      \multicolumn{16}{@{}l@{}}{Adultos mayores en hogares unipersonales\textsuperscript{a}} \\
      Varones  & 28.3 & 28.9 & 0.6
      & 21.1 & 27.8 & 6.7
      & 23.1 & 24.1 & 1.0
      & 22.3 & 23.8 & 1.5
      & 23.3 & 25.7 & 2.5 \\
      Mujeres  & 71.7 & 71.1 & -0.6
      & 78.9 & 72.2 & -6.7
      & 76.9 & 75.9 & -1.0
      & 77.7 & 76.2 & -1.5
      & 76.7 & 74.3 & -2.5 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}

    \smallskip
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item a: Como porcentaje del total de hogares unipersonales conformados por adultos mayores.
    \item Fuente: Elaboración propia en base a la EPH.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh!  Thank you so much Henri!  That's the layout I wanted! I didn't know about `siunitx`, so I'll try to learn about it.